# how to change targetName space in generated jaxb classes

Tags: java, jaxb

I have many xsd's out which i have to generate jaxb classes. now my problem is that. all the xsd's have targetName space which is not mine. i want to generate jaxb classes with different name space. every time.

I have tried this with 
targetNamespace elment in bindings.xjb in globalbindings

But i got an error saying that targetNamespace is allowed in jxb:globalbindings..

Can any one help me .. 
Thanks In Advance.
Reagrds,
PhaniKiran.Gutha

Comment: If you are able to do this then the XML produced by the generated classes won't conform to the XML schema that was used to generate them.  Is this what you asking for?

Answer (score 2):

Try using the XmlSchema annotation, e.g.:

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace="http://your.custom.namespace.com",
        elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
```

This annotation has to be placed over a package. That's why you need to create a `package-info.java` file in each package you have the objects you serialize.

You can find more information in Javadoc: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema.html